# Why won't the following PDO transaction won't work in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions, innodb

I am using PHP version 5.4.4, and a MySQL database using InnoDB. I had been using PDO for awhile without using transactions, and everything was working flawlessly. Then, I decided to try to implement transactions, and I keep getting Internal Server Error 500. The following code worked for me (doesn't contain transactions).

```
try {
    $DB = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'root', 'root');
    $DB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $dbh = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :test");

    $dbh->bindValue(':test', $test, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $dbh->execute();
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    $dbh->rollback();
    echo "an error has occured";
}
```

Then I attempted to use transactions with the following code (which doesn't work).

```
try {
    $DB = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'root', 'root');
    $DB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $dbh = $DB->beginTransaction();

    $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :test");

    $dbh->bindValue(':test', $test, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $dbh->execute();

    $dbh->commit();
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    $dbh->rollback();
    echo "an error has occured";
}
```

When I run the previous code, I get an Internal Server Error 500.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What version of MySQL and are transactions enabled? I had one hosting ISP that had the right version of MySQL, but had transactions disabled for some reason.

Comment: Check your error log. What’s the error?

Comment: `beginTransaction` returns a `boolean`, it does not return your database handler .. use `$dbh = $DB->prepare` instead .. SO is really getting annoying with all the people coming by down voting posts but not telling why ..

Comment: @dbf Thanks so much! That solved my problem! I apologize for the naive question. I am fairly new to PHP programming and PDO.

Comment: @jfizz I'll post my comment as an answer for your acceptance ratio ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$DB->beginTransaction` returns a `boolean`, it does not return your database handler (as in a prepared statement object) ..

use `$dbh = $DB->prepare` instead. You can use the return value of `$DB->beginTransaction` to check if a transaction was successfully started (it will turn off the autocommit mode).

Comment: Oh wow, a down-vote, care to comment on what your problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference your database connection handle, not the return value of the beginTransaction method. You are assigning the return value to $dbh. $dbh is not needed whatsoever. You need to use the $DB variable instead, then state your beginTransaction/commit around your PDO statements.

```
//start transaction, reference PDO handle
$DB->beginTransaction();

//In between your beginTransaction and Commit is where you will put all of your
// statements.
$DB->prepare(...);
$DB->bindValue(...);

$DB->execute();

//commit your statements once done.
$DB->commit();
```